# XSD syntax for nesting an element in another

Tags: xml, xsd

Would this be the correct way of declaring that an XML element `Cluster` contains (1 or more instances of) a single XML element type `Node`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Cluster" type="Node" minOccurs=2>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Node"/>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The textbook that I'm studying and all the online resources that I have come across exclusively discuss more complex arrangements involving `<xs:complex>` , which I suspect are overkill in this case.

Comment: This is sufficient! Add also a maxoccurs=unbounded. You can find some best practices regarding XSD & lists here: http://www.xfront.com/ElementHierarchy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your XSD is riddled with all sorts of problems. Try to use a decent XSD/XML editor, it should help you more than you think.

Problems:

- cardinality attributes (min/max Occurs) are not applicable to global element declarations.
- if you reference a type, you should have a definition of that type, simple or complex, somewhere.

I would start with a sample XML, since you know that already:

```
<Cluster>
    <Node>node1</Node>
    <Node>node2</Node>
</Cluster>
```

Then you could use the decent tool to generate the XSD, a subject that's more complicated than the simple XML you just visualized:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Cluster">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Node" type="xsd:string" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

There you could see the maxOccurs, and then change it to the value you wanted. As you become more familiar with the XSD syntax, you can start edit the working XSD into something that makes more sense; in the end, the XSD inferrence may not always be crowd pleasing...

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I'll use an XSD editor a lot more from now on.

Comment: In this example, because `nillable` is false by default, the fragment `<Cluster></Cluster>` is not valid.

Comment: @Olumide, is you wish to allow for empty content, just set the minOccurs=0 for the Node element.

Comment: I do not wish to have an empty Cluster. Will the XSD enforce this?

Comment: Yes; the way the XSD was generated, it asks for at least one (default for minOccurs is 1); you could set minOccurs=2, if you want at least two nodes, etc.

Comment: Just to confirm, the default values of minOccurs and nillable both guarantee non empty clusters. Also, if my Cluster contained heterogeneous elements and I wanted two or more of such elements. Would I set the minOccurs in Cluster?

Comment: ... or in `<xsd:complexType>`?

Comment: yes for minOccurs default value; if nillable=true then <Cluster xsi:nil="true"/> would be valid. nillable is false by default, in which case is the minOccurs of the contained particles (Node or the wrapping sequence) which decide whether empty content is allowed or not.

Comment: The example here answers my second question
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256089.aspx

Comment: thanks for suggesting that I use Try to use an XSD/XML editor. Its **really** helping. What was I thinking, trying to write a program (okay a markup language) without validating it.

Answer (score 0):

I won't try to add to the discussion on this particular schema. I would just say that you shouldn't attempt to write any kind of schema, even with the help of tools, until you have studied the language in a lot more detail. It is a very complex specification. Don't try to read the W3C specification; but do read one of the many good books on the subject, for example the one by Eric van der Vlist is very approachable. It's not a language that you can learn by trial and error.

Comment: I am reading a book (Professional XML by Bill Evjen at. al. published by Wiley) while writing my schema.

Comment: Quick question. Bearing in mind that the maxOccurs attribute of `<xsd:sequence>` has a default value of 1, shouldn't a sequence that consists of more than one element be invalid (if the maxOccurs attribute is not set to a higher value or unbounded).